# app domain in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to make a web page to post status in facebook but with scripts on FB webpage I am not able to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="return postToWall();">Post To Wall</a>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId: 'XXXX', 
      status: true, 
      cookie: true, 
      xfbml: true, 
      oauth: true });

 function postToWall() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
        if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed', 
            name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
            link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
            picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
            caption: 'Reference Documentation',
            description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
        },
        function(response) {
          if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.');
          } else {
            alert('Post was not published.');
          }
        });
  } else {
    alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
}, {scope: 'user_likes,offline_access,publish_stream'});
return false;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course I use the correct appId of my application. I have the applicacion in sandbox mode because I still has nothing, just this script. My webpage will just has this part to post and nothing else related to facebook.

I am testing it in my compunter with xampp. So I guess in facebook app domain I have to write it but everything I tried (localhost, localhost/faceapp/...) fail. For example, I get this:

```
Error
App Domains: http://localhost/appFace should not contain protocol information.
```

When the prompt appears, you can write your user and your password but the next window tells you that the webpage is not allowed in app configuration and something else. I read it in spanish so I don't know the exact sentence in english.

I have found many answet about this but most of them are from the previous version of the api ¨(which has changed since that) and the others tells to use localhost or so, and I can't save the changes in fb app writing that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading and _understand_ a simple error message.

Comment: Why people downvote answer? if you don't like, just pass it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app settings in FB, put App domain "localhost" and if your are using Login With FB, then in Site URL enter http:// localhost / (without space) or if you have created any virtual host, enter that...

Comment: Thanks man. It works. I guess I have to do the same with the final url when I upload the webpage to my server, don't I?

Comment: yes you will have to update information in the app